# NuGet newbie mayhem

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, nuget, .net-4.5

I'm really new to NuGet and having all kinds of trouble with it. So the latest problem is that I generated a bunch of .nupkg files and put them in a shared folder on the network and then set NuGet up to look there for updates. So let's say in the folder I have:

```
Author.library.2.1.0.nupkg
Author.library.2.2.0.nupkg
Author.library.2.2.1.nupkg
```

I then found out that the target framework (.net) is different for some of my projects (under the same solution), so I generated new packages for each target:

```
Author.library.net40.2.1.0.nupkg
Author.library.net40.2.2.0.nupkg
Author.library.net40.2.2.1.nupkg
Author.library.net45.2.1.0.nupkg
Author.library.net45.2.2.0.nupkg
Author.library.net45.2.2.1.nupkg
```

Next I right-clicked on the solution and chose Manage NuGet Packages for Solution and then went to Online, pointed to the Installed Packages and was able to install each package to the applicable projects (.csproj files). But now when I open the NuGet Package Manager for the solution and click on Installed Packages, all I see is once instance of library. If I click on it, on the right I can see that it's pointing to the Author.library.net45 package, but I have no way of seeing the .net40 version of the library. So I can't add it to the .40 projects.

And lastly, what if I want some of the projects to point at an older version of a package. I know that I am suppose to be able to specify that in the packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="Author.Library" version="2.2.0" allowedVersions="
     [2.0.0,2.3.0)" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

which should load anything above (and including) 2.0 through 2.3)
or

```
<package id="Author.Library" version="(,2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

which should load any version below 2.4.

So my main question is why can't I see the two versions of the package in the NuGet Package Manager? And also, how do I best limit the versions that will apply to a particular library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot see the different packages since they both have the same package id of `Author.Library`. This is based on what you have shown in your packages.config file.

Also I would not have separate NuGet packages just for assemblies that target different frameworks. Instead put them in a single NuGet package in their own lib directory (e.g. lib/net40 lib/net45). You can have multiple assemblies targeting different frameworks in the same NuGet package. NuGet will pick the best match when installing the NuGet package into the project. Also note that you can use a NuGet package that contains just .NET 4.0 assemblies with a .NET 4.5 project since the assembly is compatible.

The allowedVersions attribute in the packages.config file is the thing to use if you want to restrict the NuGet packages that a project can update to.